# open child window within parent window using kendo window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I am using one parent kendo window where i have four child window and all four child window having maximize and minimize action. When i click on maximize, it is covering full window. I want that it should maximize within parent window.
Here is my code below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    //$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
        
              
        var position = $("#WindowParent").position();

        var width = ((window.innerWidth - (window.innerWidth * 0.2)) / 2);
        var height = ((window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight * 0.2)) / 2);                
        var left = position.left + width + 15;
        var top = position.top + height + 40;

        CreateWindow("#Window1", width, height, position.left, position.top, "Qatar Airways");
        CreateWindow("#Window2", width, height, left, position.top, "History");

        CreateWindow("#Window3", width, height, position.left, top, "Corporate affairs");
        CreateWindow("#Window4", width, height, left, top, "Destinations");
    });

    
    function CreateWindow(divId, width, height, left, top, title) {
        
        jQuery(divId).kendoWindow({
            "modal": false,
            //"iframe": false,
            //"draggable": true,
            "scrollable": true,
            "pinned": true,
            "title": title,
            "resizable": false,
            "width": width,
            "height": height,
            "position": {
                "top": top,
                "left": left
            },
            //"content": null,
            "actions": ["Minimize", "Maximize"]
        });
    }
    
</script>
```

This code i am using when page is getting load and below is my html control

```html
<div id="WindowParent">    
        
    <div id="Window1">
        <p>
            Qatar Airways Company Q.C.S.C. (Arabic: القطرية, Al Qatariyah‎),operating as Qatar Airways, is the state-owned flag carrier of Qatar.
            Headquartered in the Qatar Airways Tower in Doha,the airline operates a hub-and-spoke network, linking over 140 international destinations
            across Africa, Central Asia, Europe, Far East, South Asia, Middle East, North America, South America and Oceania from its base at Hamad International Airport,
            using a fleet of more than 100 aircraft.
        </p>

        <p>
            Qatar Airways Group employs more than 31,000 people, of which 19,000 work directly for Qatar Airways.
            The carrier has been a member of the Oneworld alliance since October 2013, the first Gulf carrier to sign with one of the three airline alliances.
        </p>
        <p>
            Source:
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qatar_Airways" title="Qatar AirWays">Qatar AirWays</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Window2">
        <h1>History</h1>
        <p>
            Qatar Airways was established on 22 November 1993;operations started on 20 January 1994. Amman was first served in May 1994.
            At April 1995, the airline's CEO was the Sheikh Hamad Bin Ali Bin Jabor Al Thani who employed 75.
            By this time the fleet consisted of two Airbus A310s that served a route network including Abu Dhabi, Bangkok, Cairo, Dubai,
            Khartoum, Kuwait, London, Madras, Manila, Muscat, Osaka, Sharjah, Taipei, Tokyo and Trivandrum.
            During 1995, two ex-All Nippon Airways Boeing 747s were bought from Boeing.The airline acquired a second-hand Boeing 747SP from Air Mauritius in 1996.
        </p>

        <p>
            Services to Athens, Istanbul, Madras and Tunis were suspended in late 1996, whereas Calcutta and Muscat were removed from the route network in January and September 1997,
            respectively.Flights to London were launched during 1997.The airline also took delivery of two second-hand 231-seater Airbus A300-600R aircraft on lease from Ansett Worldwide
            Aviation Services (AWAS) during the year; they replaced two Boeing 747s. The entering of these two A300s into the fleet also marked the introduction of a new logo.
            A third A300-600R joined the fleet shortly afterwards, also on lease from AWAS.In July 1998 the carrier placed a firm order with Airbus for six Airbus A320s,
            slated for delivery between 2001 and 2005; it also took options for five more aircraft of the type.Also in 1998, the carrier struck a deal with Singapore Aircraft Leasing Enterprise (SALE)
            for the lease of four Airbus A320s, with deliveries scheduled between February and April 1999;these latter four aircraft were aimed at replacing the Boeing 727-200 Advanced fleet and to fill
            the capacity gap before the hand over of the first A320 from Airbus.The airline took delivery of the first A320 powered by Aero Engines V2500 on lease from SALE in February 1999.
        </p>

        <p>
            A fourth A300-600R on lease from AWAS joined the fleet in April 2000.In October 2000, Qatar Airways ordered an International Aero Engines V2500-powered Airbus A319CJ and took an option for
            another aircraft of the type.The airline became the Airbus A380‍‍ '​‍s ninth customer in 2001 when two aircraft of the type were ordered, plus two options.Also that year, the airline resumed
            services to Jakarta.In 2002, the government of Qatar withdrew from Gulf Air.In June 2003, a Qatar Airways Airbus A320 was the first aircraft that resumed the international services to Iraq
            when it flew the Doha–Basra route.Also that month, Qatar Airways incorporated its first dedicated cargo aircraft to the fleet. It was an Airbus A300-600R that was converted to freighter in
            Germany for US$10 million.Also in June 2003,at the Paris Air Show, the carrier placed an order with Airbus valued at US$5.1 billion for two Airbus A321s, 14 Airbus A330s and two Airbus
            A340-600s.The deal included eight A330-200s and six -300s;it also included options for further six A330-300s and eight A340-600s.The first aircraft were scheduled to enter the fleet in 2004,
            with the A340-600 slated for delivery in 2006.During the year the airline started serving the Chinese market with the introduction of flights to Shanghai.Also in 2003, the carrier expanded
            its portfolio of destinations with the commencement of services to Manchester in April,Tripoli in November,and Cebu and Singapore in December.During the 2003 Dubai Air Show the airline firmed
            up an earlier commitment for two Airbus A380s and took options for another two of these aircraft. The value of the transaction was US$1.2 billion.It was also in 2003 that Qatar Airways became
            the first airline to be audited under the new IATA operational audit programme, IOSA
        </p>

        <p>
            Source:
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qatar_Airways" title="Qatar AirWays">Qatar AirWays</a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="Window3">
        <h1>Corporate affairs</h1>
        <h2>Key people</h2>
        <p>
            As of May 2015 the Qatar Airways' CEO is Akbar Al Baker,who has been serving in this position since November 1996.Baker is also a member of the Heathrow Airport board.
        </p>
        <h2>Ownership and subsidiaries</h2>
        <p>
            As of May 2014, the company is fully owned by the Qatari government.Qatar Airways has been fully controlled by the government since July 2013,following the buyout of a 50%
            stake from a former foreign minister and other shareholders.As of September 2014, the Qatar Airways Group employs more than 31,000 people; 19,000 of them work directly for the airline.
        </p>
        <h2>Divisions</h2>
        <p>
            Qatar Airways has many divisions including: Qatar Aircraft Catering Company, Doha International Airport, Qatar Airways Holidays, United Media Int, Qatar Duty Free, Qatar Aviation Services,
            Qatar Distribution Company, and Qatar Executive.
        </p>
        <h2>Cargo</h2>
        <p>
            Qatar Airways Cargo, the airline‍‍'​‍s freight branch, has ordered three Boeing 777F.The first Boeing 777F was delivered to the airline in on May 14, 2010, and has freight facilities able to
            handle 750,000 tonnes of cargo per annum during its first development phase. The Boeing 777F will be used primarily on Qatar Airways' Far East and European routes and will be supplemented
            by Airbus A300-600F freighters operating on regional routes feeding the airline's hub.
        </p>
        <p>
            Dedicated cargo flights to Cairo International Airport were launched in June 2009 complementing the passenger services already operated.
        </p>
        <p>
            On August 18, 2010, the airline launched its first US dedicated cargo service from its hub in Doha to Chicago-O'Hare with a stop-over in Amsterdam,
            Netherlands using Boeing 777 freighter aircraft.
        </p>
        <p>
            On 13 March 2013, Qatar Airways Cargo first of three A330F was delivered provided on lease from BOC aviation replacing A300-600F.
        </p>
        <p>
            Global Supply Systems operated three Boeing 747-8F aircraft under a wet lease arrangement for British Airways World Cargo until BA terminated the contract early on 17 January 2014.
            An agreement with Qatar Airways to operate flights for IAG Cargo using Boeing 777F was announced on the same day.
        </p>
        <p>
            On 18 March 2015, Qatar Airways Cargo announced that starting 4 April 2015 will launch a twice-weekly Boeing 777 Freighter service to Los Angeles which will become
            Qatar Airways Cargo’s fourth US freighter destination alongside Houston, Chicago and Atlanta.
        </p>
        <p>
            Source:
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qatar_Airways" title="Qatar AirWays">Qatar AirWays</a>
        </p>
    </div>


    <div id="Window4">
        <h1>Destinations</h1>
        <p>
            The airline flies to all six inhabited continents.On 27 May 2014, the touchdown of a flight from Bahrain at Doha'​‍s Hamad International Airport marked the official transfer of
            Qatar Airways' operations to its new hub from Doha International Airport.
        </p>

        <p>
            As of December 2014, Qatar Airways served 146 points worldwide following the launch of flights to Asmara.The airline had previously added to the route network Dallas/Fort Worth,
            the carrier‍‍ '​‍s seventh destination in the United States and the second one in Texas along with Houston,Haneda,Miami,Edinburgh,its third destination in the United Kingdom,
            Istanbul‍‍ '​‍s Sabiha Gökçen International Airport, its third point served in Turkey,and Djibouti.Starting June 2015, the carrier will serve Amsterdam.
        </p>

        <p>
            On 8 October 2012, Qatar Airways announced it would be part of Oneworld within the forthcoming 18 months.The entrance of the carrier into the alliance was mentored by British Airways.
            The joining ceremony took place on 29 October 2013. The event marked Qatar Airways as the first of the major Gulf carriers in being part of an airline alliance.
        </p>

        <p>
            Source:
            <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qatar_Airways" title="Qatar AirWays">Qatar AirWays</a>
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

can any one help me in this.

Comment: I don't see any support in the API. As a workaround you could create two custom buttons to fake the maximize and minimize commands (minimize does not need to be faked, but it will have a consistent design). When clicking the custom maximize button, you could dynamically set width and height to that what you want, instead of the entire view area. Also, it doesn't hurt to have a look at the [`maxHeight`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-maxHeight) and [`maxWidth`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-maxWidth) properties.